# Asymptotic bounds. What software to use?

Tags: asymptotics, graphing-functions, math-software

For a pair of expressions ($A,B$), I need to determine whether $A$ is upper asymptotic, tight bound, or lower asymptotic of $B$. For example:

$$A = n^{\log(c)}$$
$$B = n^{sin(n)}$$

What (free) software and (simple) commands could I use to graph these?

I am not very experienced with using software to plot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wolfram Alpha, like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E%28sin%28n%29%29%20for%20n=%5B0,2000%5D), or [Function Plotter](https://functionplotter.com/). I prefer the latter for relatively simple expressions, because you can interactively zoom in or out with your mouse-wheel. Just add the function on the right (by default, it displays $x^2$).

As far as I know fooplot only plots functions, not sequences. In WA you can probably do both.

Comment: Thanks, Nameless, but I need to plot at least two functions at the same time, and it doesn't seem WA can do that..?

Comment: Actually you can, for example http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^2%2C+sqrt%28x%29 (copy entire link). Same for fooplot: just add another function on the right.